# python installation fails with File "setup.py", line 1023, SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, setup.py, failed-installation

I am trying to install python3.8.1 on a RHEL 7 server. It is an offline installation. 
The python folder is untared and stored in a folder in the server. 
After redirecting myself into the folder where the setup.py file is located. I run

`master1 Python-3.8.1]$ sudo python setup.py install-sh`

```
  File "setup.py", line 1023
    libraries=[panel_library, *curses_libs]))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I cant find a solution. Appreciate help

Comment: which tar/zip file you downloaded and from where?

Comment: @drd: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/Python-3.8.1.tgz from the link : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install python with source code zipped in tgz. So, you will need to ***compile*** it and then ***install*** it.

Once you unzip, refer `readme.rst` file.

> ### Build Instructions
>
> On Unix, Linux, BSD, macOS, and Cygwin::
>
> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make test
> sudo make install
> ```
>
> This will install Python as `python3`.

I think you are using command to install packages offline using `setup.py`, that won't work for python fresh installation